# Buscar una palabra dentro del la variable Files Java

Tags: java

tengo el siguiente codigo en java necesitaria buscar en el resultado devuelto el nombre de un archivo especifico, el problema es que de esta forma busco por extension y no por el nombre y no se me ocurre como hacer para realizar una busqueda por nombre.
espero me pueda ayudar.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    // Aquí la carpeta que queremos explorar
    String path = "C://Users//Federico//Downloads"; 

    String files = null;

    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            if (files.endsWith(".seq") || files.endsWith(".SEQ")){
                System.out.println(files);
            }
        }

        }String s = files;
        s.charAt(60);
    for (int x = 0; x < s.length(); x++) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Utiliza el método `contains()` en vez de `endWith()`.

Answer (score 1):

En principio, lo que deberías hacer es usar el método de la clase String `contains`, que permite buscar en una cadena la ocurrencia de otra, y por lo tanto debería valer con sustituir la línea:

```
if (files.endsWith(".seq") || files.endsWith(".SEQ")){
```

Por algo como lo siguiente:

```
 if (files.toLowerCase().contains("seq")){
```

Por cierto, he pasado antes a minúsculas la cadena, para que no tengas que buscarlo de dos formas distintas.

Puedes consultar el API de String en :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Muchas Gracias Gatcgman

Answer (score 1):

Estas buscando por extensión ya que el método busca si la cadena termina con `.seq`

> **[endsWith()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String))** : Prueba si esta cadena termina con el sufijo
>   especificado.

si deseas buscar el texto dentro del nombre del archivo puedes usar el método:

> **[contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))** : Devuelve verdadero si y solo si esta cadena contiene la secuencia especificada de valores de char.

Por lo tanto en lugar de:

```
 if (files.endsWith(".seq") || files.endsWith(".SEQ")){
   System.out.println(files);
 }
```

Puedes cambiar a :

```
String textoBuscar = ".seq"; //Define aquí el texto a buscar.
if (files.contains(textoBuscar)){
   System.out.println(files);
}
```

si deseas buscar el texto  no importando mayúsculas o minúsculas puedes agregar además el método [toLowerCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase())

```
String textoBuscar = ".SeQ"; //Define aquí el texto a buscar.
if (files.toLowerCase().contains(textoBuscar)){
   System.out.println(files);
}
```